# Sterling NoSQL OODB

Tags: nosql

Недавно наткнулся на интересный топик на Хабре - [Введение в Sterling NoSQL OODB](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/nosql/132114/) - описывающий достаточно свежую NoSQL БД.

Стоит ли попытаться её использовать?

Хотелось бы выслушать мнения тех, кто может быть её использовал, плюсы-минусы, сложности, нюансы использования, возможно баги.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Стоит ли попытаться её использовать?

Против этой базы ничего не имею, так как не использовал. Но, в своих проектах ПОКА НЕ БУДУ ее использовать - проект свежий, не известно какие баги и ограничения в ней выявятся (заточена под Net-, Win-платформу ?!), под какой лицензией будет распространяться (их сервер не в данный момент не работает). 
Как на побаловаться-потестировать вполне можно. В реальных проектах вместо нее я рекомендую использовать похожую по "философии" SQLite - все таки поддержка SQL-языка всегда актуальна.
Напоследок, почитайте там же статью "[**Реляционные базы данных обречены?**](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/nosql/103021/#habracut)"

Comment: Прошу прощения за поклеп: их сервер работает - почему-то мой провайдер (Казахтелеком) их блокирует :(